# BUG with href containing Anchor #id - hits top of page for split second before jumping to Anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bug in my site and I’m having trouble finding an elegant solution. I bet there’s a simple way to fix this .. I’m just not seeing it. I would appreciate any suggestions.

example: http://robbroadwell.com/portfolio/ios-apps/rainylectures/

The detail pages on my portfolio have a main nav and then below that a sub nav. If the user has scrolled down below the main nav where it’s out of sight, I’m using jQuery to append the href of the left/right arrows with an anchor tag so that the main nav is hidden on the page they navigate to.

The problem is about 25% of the time the browser hits the destination page at the TOP for a SPLIT SECOND before it jumps down to the anchor tag, so you see the top nav for just a second. It looks buggy and bad.

Thoughts… should I use CSS transitions to hide it? Should I pass a value in the URL and then pick up on it on the destination page to set the main nav to display: none, and then if the browser is at the top of the window and the user scrolls up, add it back in?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Also, apologies to those on Mobile devices - you won't be able to access that page! I redirect /mobile/ to a different experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already pass a value in the url: `#local-nav`

I didn't test it... But I think this could work:

```
if(location.hash){
    $(".navbar-absolute-top").css("visibility","hidden");
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".navbar-absolute-top").css("visibility","visible");
    },500);
}
```

-------
**EDIT** based on comment
Okay then...

What if you set the non-visibility in CSS?

```
.navbar-absolute-top{
    visibility=hidden;
}
```

Then we decide when to set it visible.
If there a hash in the url ==> wait... If not ==> Don't wait!
;)

```
if(location.hash){
    // Holds on before setting the main nav visible
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".navbar-absolute-top").css("visibility","visible");
    },500);
}else{
    // Sets the main nav visible right now
    $(".navbar-absolute-top").css("visibility","visible");
}
```

`500`ms may need to be adjusted
;)


-------
**EDIT** based on comment

About "choppy effect"... Maybe `animate()` will give a smoother effect using `opacity`:

```
body{
    opacity=0;
}


if(location.hash){
    // Holds on before setting the main nav visible
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("body").animate({"opacity":1},200);
    },50);
}else{
    // Sets the main nav visible right now
    $("body").animate({"opacity":1},200);
}
```

**to complete the effect**... You should add a `$("body").animate({"opacity":"0"},200);` in a `paddle-nav-item a` `.click()` handler that will redirect on `.animate` callback:

```
$(".paddle-nav-item a").click(function(e){

    // Hold the click event
    e.preventDefault();
    // Opacity effect
    $("body").animate({"opacity":"0"},200,function(){

        // Callback retreive the href and redirect AFTER the animation has completed
        redirectTo = $(this).attr("href");
        location.assign(redirectTo);
    });
});
```

;)

Comment: I don't really like « isn't a way around»... I had another idea.

Comment: Thanks Louys. I tested that, and it still starts at the top and jumps down, but instead of seeing the black nav bar, it's just white space. I think we're tackling the problem from the wrong direction...

Removing the nav bar as opposed to making the #anchor happen before the user sees anything - maybe CSS transitions?

Comment: Hum... ok so there's a "missing"  element effect... And What if the whole `body` was not visible instead of only the main nav ?

Comment: Check it out now: http://robbroadwell.com/portfolio/ios-apps/rainylectures/

It works - you don't see the top bar at all, added a 50ms timer to fade in the body content. It just looks 'choppy', it breaks the cohesiveness of the experience a bit. I might need to slide left, slide right transitions when the arrows are used to slide the entire body off and on to the screen

Comment: Thanks for your help Louys!

Comment: Edited about "choppy effect". ;)

Comment: I changed CSS attrribute since animate need a numeric value... ;)

Comment: I suggested `200`ms for `animate()` delay... But longer will be smoother. Should not be too long ;)

Comment: I see that you completely changed the transition approach. ;) Good idea, it's nice!